# Getting incorrect values when accessing variables passed along in a pointer to a character array for strtok

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strtok

Here is my code

```
//Split up the config by lines
int x;
int numberOfConfigLines = 0;
for (x = 0; x < strlen(buffer); x++)
{
    if (buffer[x] == '\n') {
        numberOfConfigLines++;
    }
}
char *configLines[numberOfConfigLines];
tokenize(configLines, buffer, "\n", numberOfConfigLines);
```

The idea of this function is to count the amount of newlines in a buffer, then split the buffer into a strtok array using this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void tokenize(char **arrToStoreTokens, char *delimitedString, char *delimiter, int expectedTokenArraySize) {
    //Create a clone of the original string to prevent making permanent changes to it
    char *tempString = (char *)malloc(strlen(delimitedString) + 1);
    strcpy(tempString, delimitedString);

    if (expectedTokenArraySize >= 1) {
    arrToStoreTokens[0] = strtok(tempString, delimiter);

        int x;
        for (x = 1; x < expectedTokenArraySize; x++ ) {
            arrToStoreTokens[x] = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        }
    }

    //Dispose of temporary clone
    free(tempString); 
}
```

If I access `arrToStoreTokens[0]` directly, I get the correct result, however when I try to access `configLines[0]` once the`tokenize` function has ended, I get different results (can be unknown characters or simply empty)

<strike>Additionally, I believe this has only started occurring once I began running the program as root (for a different requirement) - I may be wrong though.</strike> - EDIT: Confirmed not to be the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, just checked, problem persists when not in root

Comment: BTW, Don't cast the result of `malloc` and family

Comment: Would you be able to answer with a corrected version, I don't really come from a memory allocation background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) doesn't reallocate anything. It only makes cut and pointers of what you gave to it.

Your array stores pointers that strtok gives you, but don't copy contents.

So if you free your `tempString` variable, you free data that was pointed by return values of strtok. You have to keep it and free it only at the end.

Or you can make a [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) of each return of strtok to store it in your array to make a real copy of each token, but in this case, you shall have to free each token at the end.

The second solution would looks like this :

```
void tokenize(char **arrToStoreTokens, char *delimitedString, char *delimiter, int expectedTokenArraySize) {
    //Create a clone of the original string to prevent making permanent changes to it
    char *tempString = (char *)malloc(strlen(delimitedString) + 1);
    strcpy(tempString, delimitedString);

    if (expectedTokenArraySize >= 1) {
    arrToStoreTokens[0] = strdup(strtok(tempString, delimiter)); // Here is the new part : strdup

        int x;
        for (x = 1; x < expectedTokenArraySize; x++ ) {
            arrToStoreTokens[x] = strdup(strtok(NULL, delimiter)); // Here is the new part : strdup
        }
    }

    //Dispose of temporary clone
    free(tempString); 
}
```

And after use of this array, you shall have to delete it, with a function like this :

```
void deleteTokens(char **arrToStoreTokens, int arraySize)
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < arraySize; ++x)
    {
        free(arrToStoreTokens[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I thought I was writing the output of strtok to ` arrToStoreTokens[x]`?

Comment: You didn't copy the contents, only the address. I edited my answer.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your answer with a corrected version of code?

Comment: Example added. Any more trouble ?